# Rubber be kashered

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, contemporary-halacha, responsa, yoreh-deah

Can rubber be kashered? From what I understand, to be kashered something has to be heated up in boiling hot water, in the case of rubber, I don’t believe it can absorb and retain heat internally. If this is the case, would it be impossible to make a non kosher spatula kosher? Is there a Halacha brought down one way or the other on the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R’ Moshe in Igros Moshe [OC 2:92](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=285&hilite=) says that rubber made from trees is able to be kashered but synthetic rubber (silicone, etc) can’t, as it is something new that isn’t found in earlier sources

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciated @chatzkel